# macOS Keychain Create Uneditable Access Group Entry

Tags: macos, security, terminal, keychain

Xcode has an internet password that it stores in the keychain with a specific access group. I am trying to replicate this using the `security` command line tool, but I'm not sure how to provide a non application binary for access.

`security add-internet-password -a "USER" -w "PASS" -s sample.com -A`

How would I go about including the `59GAB85EFG.com.apple.dt.Xcode`?

[image: KeychainEntry]